# Why is my VBA function returning 0?

Tags: function, vba, recursion

Consider the following function in VBA (note that it's been edited based on the answers given so now it's working - see the edit history for the original version):

```
Function DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes)

    Dim xNode As Object
    For Each xNode In Nodes

        If xNode.nodeName = "LastTradePriceOnly" Then
            DisplayNode = xNode.Text
            Exit Function
        End If
        If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
            DisplayNode = DisplayNode (xNode.ChildNodes)
        End If

   Next xNode

End Function
```

This function parses an XML response and returns the value of one of the nodes, `LastTradePriceOnly`.

The Nodes argument is a `MSXML.DOMDocument` object. When I use `msgBox` to print the value of `xNode.text` the value I am expecting is output. However, when I call this function from another function, 0 is returned.

Any thoughts on why I might be returning 0?

Comment: You may want to reduce the amount of pain in your life and look into [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). Why reinvent the wheel and write your own functions for XML lookups? It's all there for you in XPath already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alains's answer gets at the root of your problem but doesn't go all the way.

Perhaps you need to recall that a line like `DisplayNode = xNode.Text` just tells VBA what to return upon function exit, but doesn't actually exit the function. VBA will happily let you assign and reassign the return value, and will just return whatever you told it to last.

Also, if you never assign a value to the function, VBA will assume you wanted to return the default value of whatever the type of the function is. In your case, your function is of type `Variant`, and the default value of `Variant` is `Empty`. You might be seeing this as zero, because VBA implicitly converts `Empty` to zero in all kinds of situations

With that in mind, consider what happens in your example if any of these are true:

1) your `Nodes` parameter doesn't have anything in it (i.e. it's an empty array or Collection or whatever it is in MSXML)

2) there are some nodes, but none of them meet either of the tests in your loop

3) there are some nodes, and the last node satisfies (1) or (2) above

You should be able to see that your function will return `Empty`, even if it found one or more "LastTradePriceOnly" nodes on it's way through your tree of nodes. And then you would see that as zero when you display it in a message box.

It sounds like you really want a more specific routine - maybe something that finds a specific node in a tree and raises an error if it can't do so. I guess it depends on your data, but this explanation should address your immediate question about why you could be seeing zero in your message box.

Comment: I had a strong suspicion the VBA does not exit the function upon assignment. See the modified code above, which works. Note that this is quick and dirty hence the lack of error checking/handling.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to actually return the value from your recursive call:

**DisplayNode =** DisplayNode (xNode.ChildNodes)

Been there :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I altered the function but it is still returning 0. See edited question above.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you should change this:

```
Function DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes)
```

to this:

```
Function DisplayNode(Nodes as MSXML2.DOMDocument) as String
```

ByRef happens by default in VBA so you don't have to include it unless you want to.
Also, not declaring variables or functions defaults them to Variants.  Doing this is generally considered a bad coding practice plus you don't get the advantage of IntelliSense.

You might also want to change your declaration of xNode.  I haven't worked with DOMDocument before, but if there's more than one different type of object, then the FOR EACH statement will loop through them all; looks like you may only want to loop through one kind of object.

Finally, could the property you want to use be *nodeValue* and not *Text*?

When I look in the object browser, the definition for nodeValue is *value stored in the node*.

However, text is *text content of the node and subtree*.

Comment: I cannot declare MSXML2.DOMDocument because I cannot assume my users have the XML reference. That's why everything is pretty generic.

Comment: @strimp099 Question:  how would the code in the example run for your clients if there was no reference to the XML DLL?

Comment: Late binding. `Set Nodes = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")` or something like that.

Comment: Bah...right.  I got tunnel-vision.  Regardless, **Function DisplayNode(Nodes as Object) as String** would be a better declaration.

Comment: Jean-François Corbett - right; @ray023 you're right there - I've modified the function +1 - thanks again.